# Why is there no Stack Overflow на Русском in the Top Network Sites list on stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, russian-stackoverflow

https://stackexchange.com/

> [image]

But on https://stackexchange.com/sites we are on the 6th place:

> [image]

And I can't find the sort order on https://stackexchange.com/sites page, which fit order on the main page.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ mb because here https://stackexchange.com/sites it's on the 6th place. Duno.

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8796/15479

Comment: This might be one of the places where localized sites are filtered out. I know for a fact that the HNQ filters out localized sites, for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That list of sites is sorted according to what StackExchange.com considers to be the "default" sort. It's a value calculated per site that's a combination of total question and answer counts, answered %, total users, and daily visits, sorted in the descending order.

Specifically:

```
((TotalQs + (TotalAs / 3)) * PercentAnswered / 100) + TotalUsers + VisitsPerDay
```

I have no idea why that formula is what it is, but this sort can't be replicated on /sites, which is why you're seeing a different ordering. You can see the sites ordered by this formula on the [Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) page.

Comment: What position number should be for ruSO according to the published formula?

Comment: Also, why  can't "this sort be replicated on /sites"?

Comment: @Suvitruf It's inaccessible through the UI on /sites. But I just found out that /leagues uses the same sort, so you can see SOru's position there.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Turns out, /leagues on se.com sorts the sites using the same ordering, so it looks like SOru is #11.

Comment: I wonder, was that formula ever exposed before?

Comment: @ShadowWizard ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯