# How are the "Top Network Sites" determined?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

On the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/), there's a widget "Top Network Sites" in the right sidebar, underneath the list of users who asked the currently hot network questions.

[image]

I was wondering how this list was determined (specifically, how Ask Different ended up there). My initial guess was that one of the metrics on the [All Sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) would be used, but I couldn't find which one. Sorting by [total number of questions](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) has the first five sites right, ru.SO might be skipped since it's not in English, but I'd expect the next one to be TeX - LaTeX, not Unix & Linux. The difference between the figures is large enough that it can't really be caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using a complex formula which is mentioned in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324210/152859):

> `((TotalQs + (TotalAs / 3)) * PercentAnswered / 100) + TotalUsers + VisitsPerDay`

So the "Top Network Sites" is a list of the top 10 sites after sorting all sites using that formula.

Comment: Huh, I searched for "Top Network Sites" but somehow missed that question. Thanks!